# Oracle hierarchical query join to selection of all decendants

Tags: oracle, hierarchical

I am trying to retrieve a list of each descendant with each item.
I am not sure I am making sense, I will try and explain.

Example Data:

```
ID | PID
--------
1  | 0
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 1
5  | 2
6  | 2
7  | 5
8  | 3
```

etc...

The desired results are:

```
ID | Decendant
--------------
1  | 1
1  | 2
1  | 3
1  | 4
...
2  | 2
2  | 5
2  | 6
2  | 7
3  | 3
3  | 8
```

etc...

This is currently being achieved by using a cursor to move through the data and inserting each descendant into a table and then selecting from them.

I was wondering if there was a better way to do these, there must be a way to right a query that would bring back the desired results.

If any one has ideas, or has figured this out before it would be very appreciated. Ordering is not important, nor is the 1 - 1, 2 -2 reference. It would be cool to have it, but not crucial.

Comment: Are you sure? 1-4 is valid? With what ever example data shown here. Sorry, I am confused with PID column!

Comment: PID is Parent ID, maybe I should have specified that, so the Parent ID of 4 is 1.

So 4 is a descendant of 1, so 1 - 4 is valid.

Comment: @OracleUser, if you think my question is confusing I can try rewording it, but I am not sure how

Comment: i think I understood! Also, every id is descendan to itself also it seems.

Comment: I would like it shown that way in the results, but it is not essential, I can easily work around it if it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select connect_by_root(id) as ID, id as Decendant
from table1
connect by prior id = pid
order by 1, 2
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b98d7/5)

Comment: that actually worked, thank you so much.

I am guessing it has something to do with the connect_by_root()?
I will look that up, it is not something that I have come across before.

I have user connect by prior, but only for a "more flat" list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt! Not sure, if I got you right!

```
select pid ,connect_By_root(id) as descendant from process
connect by  id = prior pid
union all
select distinct pid,pid from
process
order by pid,descendant
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, it is amazing how simple some Oracle Queries can be.

Comment: @JonathanPeel Cool.. Upper portion identifies a parent.. and track all it's children.. the lower portion is what your additional requirement, Map PArent to PArent itself!

Comment: I did understand the second part, and why it was there.

I have used connect by prior before, but have never come across connect_by_root(), Thank you.